# How to understand singly linked list in python and their in-place change?

Tags: python, linked-list

What I want is: convert a give list, e.g. `a = [3, 7, 5, 8]`, to a singly linked list.

Node definition:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self,val):
    self.val = val
    self.next = None
a = [3, 7, 5, 8]
```

CODE-1:

```
## CODE-1
cur = dummy = Node(a[0])
for e in a[1::]:
    cur.next,cur = Node(e),cur.next
```

CODE-2:

```
## CODE-2
cur = dummy = Node(a[0])
for e in a[1::]:
    cur.next = Node(e)
    cur = cur.next
# the following code outputs result
cur = dummy
while cur is not None:
    print(cur.val)
    cur = cur.next
```

[image: Outputs of above two pieces of code]

Question one: I know that CODE-2 outputs what I need, but I just wonder that why don't CODE-1 work? There must be something with it.

Question two: Is there any good method to help me better understand during next-time programming?

---

Finally, the reason for why CODE-1 doesn't work is: (in CODE-1) Firstly when `e=7`, `cur` becomes `None`. Then secondly when `e=5`, `cur.next` executes `None.next`, producing an error "Type' object has no attribute 'next'". Exactly what happened with CODE-1 is shown as

```
                       e = a[1]                                    e = a[2]
operation  Node(a[0])  cur.next,cur=Node(e),cur.next   then        cur.next,cur=Node(e),cur.next   
cur        3|pointer   None                            None        right-hand-side cur.next raises an error "NoneType has no attribute 'next' " and then exit   
cur.next   None        7|pointer                       (No definition)
```

Comment: Precisely because in the first version you're not checking that cur.next doesn't return None. It does.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you very much. After carefully checking, I now know why CODE-1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In assignments, Python retrieves the values of the right-hand side expression *first*, then uses that value to make the assignments.

So

```
cur.next,cur = Node(e),cur.next
```

stores `Node(e)` and `cur.next` on the stack. `cur.next` is `None` here. The next step is to assign the two values, so `cur.next` is assigned the new node, and `cur` is assigned `None`.

From the [assignment statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

You can also see this when you [disassemble](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) the expression into bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('cur.next,cur = Node(e),cur.next')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (Node)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (e)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (cur)
              8 LOAD_ATTR                3 (next)
             10 ROT_TWO
             12 LOAD_NAME                2 (cur)
             14 STORE_ATTR               3 (next)
             16 STORE_NAME               2 (cur)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Instructions 0, 2 and 4 execute `Node(e)`, leaving it on the stack, 6 and 8 execute `cur.next`, leaving `None` on the stack. `ROT_TWO` then swaps the top two elements, so `Node(e)` is now on top, and 12 and 14 assign that to `cur.next` (clearing it from the stack), followed by 16, which stores `None` in `cur`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know that after assignment, `cur = None`. That's why it raises an error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'".